# Drop down box used to delete records sqlite

Tags: php, forms, sqlite, drop-down-menu, sql-delete

I am currently struggling with creating a drop down box that when populated will delete whichever record is currently highlighted.

I have been able to create a form that allows me to add new records to the database, but since then have really struggled to get the correct records to show on the drop down box as I only have a vague understanding of PHP.

```
<?php
$db=sqlite_open("/wwwroot/Work/bookDB.db");
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $Author = $_POST['Author'];
    $Title = $_POST['Title'];
    $Synopsis = $_POST['Synopsis'];
    $ISBN = $_POST['ISBN'];
    $Publisher = $_POST['Publisher'];
    sqlite_query ($db, "INSERT INTO Books (Author, Title, Synopsis, ISBN, Publisher)
                        VALUES ('$Author', '$Title', '$Synopsis', '$ISBN', '$Publisher')");
    header("Location: /Work/Book/Book.php"); 
}
else 
{
}
?>
```

this is my submit query that may give some understanding of how the database is set up, I am looking to have a drop down box that will be populated by a list of the authors. So far I have tried using $row to no avail, and I don't seem to be able to use $column either, like I have stated earlier my PHP skills are awful so any help would really be appreciated.

html:

```
<form name = "delete form" action="Delete.php" method="POST">
<div class = "book">
<select name = "Title">
<option value = ""> Select </option>
</div>
```

php:

```
<form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="get">
<select name = 'rowno' onchange = "javascript:document.forms[0].submit();">
<option> Select a Book </option>

<?php

$db = sqlite_open("/wwwroot/work/bookDB.db");
$query = sqlite_query($db,"SELECT ID, Title from Books");
$result = sqlite_fetch_all($query, SQLITE_BOTH);
$rowno = 0;

foreach($result as $entry)
{
    echo "<option value = $rowno >$entry[ID] $entry[Title]</option>";
    $rowno++;
}
?>
</select>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you having problems with displaying / creating the list or deleting them?

Comment: I think I should be able to get the delete function down as I was able to get the creation function, but I am really struggling with getting the records to display! Sorry for not being more descriptive!

Comment: Could you include (In your answer) What you have tried? I mean your attempts with $row, $coloumn and preferably your SELECT query too?

Comment: I've updated it, I ended up deleting the $column script I wrote as I didnt think that was a variable I could use

Comment: Is that all your php code? and where is the php code placed according to the HTML?

Comment: Ah, I had been trying to run it from the form method, which would make no sense as that would be trying to populate the list after I have clicked the delete button. Instead I'm probably going to start trying a seperate php for populating and deleting it, as that would be much easier I can assume?

Comment: That would be a good start :)

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you, but I think I am getting the hang of it! Using this resource (https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/312923/php-pdosqlite-reading-selected-dropdown-value) I have been able to create the drop down box, but I am now having trouble populating it! Again any help would really be appreciated! :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I finally got it completed myself with the help of (http://www.djhweb.co.uk/sqlite1.htm and http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-fetch-all.php) I was able to link the database in order to get it to show a drop down box of all the items in my database!

Once again many thanks, I will update for others to see.

Comment: With just a quick glance things looks to be right, glad to hear you solved the.problem yourself